# Spree Mutli Currency Converter

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems, spree, spree-paypal-express

I am using spree for my shopping cart and i want multi currency support so i use below gem in my gemfile

```
gem "spree_multi_currency", :git => "git://github.com/pronix/spree-multi-currency.git"
```

and than did bundle install

```
rake spree_multi_currency:install:migrations
rake db:migrate
```

And then load currency using below code

```
rake spree_multi_currency:currency:iso4217
```

Now I want to Load rates from google and make USD as default currency 
for that i type it on terminal

```
rake spree_multi_currency:rates:google[USD]
```

but it gives error like

```
Loads currency data from Google using #<Spree::Currency:0xb967020>
```

http://www.google.com/ig/calculator?hl=en&q=1INR%3D%3FEUR
rake aborted!
757: unexpected token at 
/home/tps/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/json-1.8.1/lib/json/common.rb:155:in `parse'
/home/tps/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/json-1.8.1/lib/json/common.rb:155:in`parse'
/home/tps/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bundler/gems/spree-multi-currency-0abaa72ab8ed/lib/tasks/spree_multi_currency.rake:126:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
/home/tps/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/relation/delegation.rb:13:in`each'
/home/tps/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/relation/delegation.rb:13:in `each'
/home/tps/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bundler/gems/spree-multi-currency-0abaa72ab8ed/lib/tasks/spree_multi_currency.rake:122:in`block (3 levels) in '
/home/tps/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
/home/tps/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in`'
Tasks: TOP => spree_multi_currency:rates:google
(See full trace by running task with --trace)

I want multi currency support for my shopping cart please help.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add currency rate from admin side. for example USD basic currency than in converter you select your currency(INR), set nominal rate means 1 usd = 63 INR than as nominal you take 63 as nominal and 1 as value.